# Spring REST: always getting "405 method not allowed" if some exception happens inside controller

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I expect exceptions thrown inside controller methods to be converted to **500 internal server error**, but I'm getting **405 method not allowed** exception in client side, no matter what exceptions occurs inside controller method.

### NOTE:

There is nothing wrong with request mappings, as it goes to expected method when I debug it. But when an exception is throw from controller methods, I get "405 method not allowed" in my client

### NOTE 2:

I tried catching exceptions and throwing `HttpServerErrorException` with appropriate error code and message, but nothing changed!

### EDIT:

I do use spring security and here is the config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

/*

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
*/

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/session/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/lib/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/templates/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/dial/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/names/**").permitAll()
//                    .antMatchers("/workflows/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/#/login").permitAll();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                new UnauthorizedLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login.html"),
                new ELRequestMatcher("hasHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest')"));
               /* .logout()
                    .permitAll();*/
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you share your method along with PUT request URL you using!!! Are you using spring security too ?? if yes then security config what you using is also helpful.

Comment: There's an exception advice mapping *exception* to 405? Can you provide an simple example that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: @Avis I do use spring security. I added my config to the post.
I'm sure it really isn't the matter of URL mapping. However I suspect there is some kind of exception filtering going on which I have no idea where it is coming from. maybe there is something with spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was because of existence of a bean of type `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`.
I removed it and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I could found this on the exception handler for Spring Data REST controller:-

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = RepositoryRestExceptionHandler.class)
public class RepositoryRestExceptionHandler {

    /**
     * Send {@code 405 Method Not Allowed} and include the supported {@link org.springframework.http.HttpMethod}s in the
     * {@code Allow} header.
     *
     * @param o_O the exception to handle.
     * @return
     */
    @ExceptionHandler
    ResponseEntity<Void> handle(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException o_O) {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAllow(o_O.getSupportedHttpMethods());

        return response(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, headers);
    }
}
```

Can you try this on your main spring boot class (i hope your project classpath starts with folder COM) :-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com"})
```